# Raspberry Pi apache2 intranet connection problem

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, webserver, intranet

I recently used Raspberry Pi to build an intranet server. I hope it can achieve the effect: as long as the terminal connected to the same wifi can access the intranet server I built through IP. But now there is a problem. My Raspberry Pi can start the apache service normally, and I can access index.html through localhost or ip (127.0.0.1). But my other computers (under the same wifi) cannot access this server through IP. Is there anyone who can solve this problem for me? Thank you! live long and prosper!

I only modified some configuration parameters in apache2.conf, Other settings are default。

Related information is as follows:
Raspberry pi 3b+ (Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v7+)
Server version: Apache/2.4.56 (Raspbian)
another pc: win11

Some pictures are as follows：
[Raspberry screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWfkM.png)
[another pc screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf5tS.png)

Some modified settings are as follows：（from apache2.conf）

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Comment: Check if you have firewall turned on and allowed for connections via port 80 in the raspberry pi. Otherwise, it won't allow access.